# by default, will plinq use range partitioning or chunk partitioning for Dictionary<string, string>? and how to force the other?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

By default, will plinq use range partitioning or chunk partitioning for a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

This is my use case:

```
    Dictionary<string,string> asmachtas = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    ...
    int sum = asmachtas.AsParallel().Sum(arg => myFunction(arg));
```

How can I check this myself? How can I force the other type of partitioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range partitioning only applies to collections that implement IList<>. Dictionary<,> only implements IEnumerable<> and not IList<>, so chunk partitioning would be used.

The partitioning algorithm used by PLINQ is an implementation detail, so you don't really have a way to look it up. You could put a breakpoint into the delegate passed into Sum() and deduce the partitioning scheme from the call stacks, but the stacks are rather messy.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx mentions that AsParallel is defined by ParallelEnumerable, so i thought it was the other way round

Answer (score 1):

As Igor said, the query would be using chunk partitioning.

I'd like to add that converting it `asmachtas.ToList().AsParallel()` would make it use range partitioning. Or if you were working with a list you can create a chunk-partitioner with `Partitioner.Create(asmachtas, true)`.